# Pagination and Sorting for locale specific values

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

**Scenario:**

I have 2 Services ServiceA and ServiceB and in both, we have one column name_key. name_key is the reference to another table lang_data where we are storing the name in different locales.
Currently, both services have the same table and code(Mostly Duplicate Code but not entirely because of entity mapping of ServiceA and ServiceB). We are using spring-data specification API to build the joins between these 2 tables and fetch the result.

I have to keep locale-specific information in the database as we need to provide pagination/sorting/search/filters with other parameters.

In case I treat lang_data as common then the mapping of entity from each service needs to be done in that. which again seems wrong.

**Question:**

1. Is this the correct way of doing things as we are duplicating the things? With an increasing number of services, it will increase.
2. Any better way to handle such a situation or any suggestion?

**Technology Used:**
Java/spring boot

Comment: If you're duplicating code, then most likely yes - there's a better way of doing it. From the description I couldn't understand why you need to duplicate it. If you have some `Blah` entity which references `LocalizedName` (or a `Map<String/*locale*/, LocaliziedName>`) then you don't have to duplicate anything, rightB

Comment: Or do you mean you have completely different entities, but every entity needs to have some i18n associated with it? And there is some duplicated logic related to handling i18n?

Comment: Yes, ServiceA has its own ServiceAEntity  and LangDataEntity and they are associated with OneToMany and ManyToOne annotations. Similar way for ServiceB service

Comment: Yeah.. that's harder. Do you mind sharing the logic that's duplicated?